# ImageMagick library not being found

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, ocr, wand

I'm working on following this guide https://pythontips.com/2016/02/25/ocr-on-pdf-files-using-python/#comments trying to build something for a friend and gain practice.

I'm having trouble with ImageMagick, this is the traceback im getting

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 180, in <module>
    libraries = load_library()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 135, in load_library
    raise IOError('cannot find library; tried paths: ' + repr(tried_paths))
OSError: cannot find library; tried paths: []

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kunbargi/Documents/Untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wand.image import Image
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .api import MagickPixelPacket, libc, libmagick, library
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 206, in <module>
    'Try to install:\n  ' + msg)
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 180, in <module>
    libraries = load_library()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 135, in load_library
    raise IOError('cannot find library; tried paths: ' + repr(tried_paths))
OSError: cannot find library; tried paths: []

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kunbargi/Documents/Untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wand.image import Image
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .api import MagickPixelPacket, libc, libmagick, library
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 206, in <module>
    'Try to install:\n  ' + msg)
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-mac
-------install:
  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-mac
```

---

I've tried following that link and installing it via brew and ports

When I do `ports installed` in terminal I get the following list, which shows that ImageMagick was installed (line 5)

```
The following ports are currently installed:
  autoconf @2.69_5 (active)
  automake @1.15_1 (active)
  bzip2 @1.0.6_0 (active)
  db48 @4.8.30_4 (active)
  djvulibre @3.5.27_0 (active)
  expat @2.2.0_0 (active)
  fftw-3 @3.3.5_0 (active)
  fontconfig @2.12.1_1 (active)
  freetype @2.7.1_0 (active)
  gdbm @1.13_1 (active)
  gettext @0.19.8.1_0 (active)
  ghostscript @9.19_0+x11 (active)
  giflib @4.2.3_0+x11 (active)
  ilmbase @2.2.0_0 (active)
  ImageMagick @6.9.8-3_0+x11 (active)
  jbig2dec @0.13_0 (active)
  jbigkit @2.1_0 (active)
  jpeg @9b_0 (active)
  lcms2 @2.8_0 (active)
  libedit @20160903-3.1_1 (active)
  libiconv @1.15_0 (active)
  libidn @1.33_0 (active)
  libpaper @1.1.24.4_0 (active)
  libpng @1.6.29_0 (active)
  libtool @2.4.6_2 (active)
  libxml2 @2.9.4_0 (active)
  ncurses @6.0_0 (active)
  openexr @2.2.0_1 (active)
  openjpeg @2.1.2_0 (active)
  openssl @1.0.2k_0 (active)
  perl5 @5.24.1_0+perl5_24 (active)
  perl5.24 @5.24.1_0 (active)
  pkgconfig @0.29.2_0 (active)
  python2_select @0.0_2 (active)
  python27 @2.7.13_0 (active)
  python_select @0.3_7 (active)
  readline @6.3.003_1 (active)
  sqlite3 @3.18.0_0 (active)
  tiff @4.0.7_0 (active)
  urw-fonts @1.0.7pre44_0 (active)
  webp @0.6.0_0 (active)
  xorg-kbproto @1.0.7_0 (active)
  xorg-libice @1.0.9_0 (active)
  xorg-libpthread-stubs @0.3_0 (active)
  xorg-libsm @1.2.2_0 (active)
  xorg-libX11 @1.6.4_0 (active)
  xorg-libXau @1.0.8_0 (active)
  xorg-libxcb @1.12_2+python27 (active)
  xorg-libXdmcp @1.1.2_0 (active)
  xorg-libXext @1.3.3_0 (active)
  xorg-libXt @1.1.5_1 (active)
  xorg-xcb-proto @1.12_1+python27 (active)
  xorg-xextproto @7.3.0_0 (active)
  xorg-xproto @7.0.31_0 (active)
  xz @5.2.3_0 (active)
  zlib @1.2.11_0 (active)
```

and doing `help('modules')` in python returns
this list which shows `pyocr, pytesseract, wand`

```
>>> help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

Cython              _tkinter            heapq               sched
OleFileIO_PL        _tracemalloc        hmac                secrets
PIL                 _warnings           html                select
Tesseract           _weakref            http                selectors
Untitled            _weakrefset         idlelib             setuptools
__future__          abc                 imaplib             shelve
_ast                aifc                imghdr              shlex
_asyncio            antigravity         imp                 shutil
_bisect             argparse            importlib           signal
_blake2             array               inspect             site
_bootlocale         ast                 io                  six
_bz2                asynchat            ipaddress           smtpd
_codecs             asyncio             itertools           smtplib
_codecs_cn          asyncore            json                sndhdr
_codecs_hk          atexit              keyword             socket
_codecs_iso2022     audioop             lib2to3             socketserver
_codecs_jp          base64              linecache           sqlite3
_codecs_kr          bdb                 locale              sre_compile
_codecs_tw          binascii            logging             sre_constants
_collections        binhex              lzma                sre_parse
_collections_abc    bisect              macpath             ssl
_compat_pickle      builtins            macurl2path         stat
_compression        bz2                 magickwand          statistics
_crypt              cProfile            mailbox             string
_csv                calendar            mailcap             stringprep
_ctypes             cgi                 marshal             struct
_ctypes_test        cgitb               math                subprocess
_curses             chunk               mimetypes           sunau
_curses_panel       cmath               mmap                symbol
_datetime           cmd                 modulefinder        symtable
_dbm                code                multiprocessing     sys
_decimal            codecs              netrc               sysconfig
_dummy_thread       codeop              nis                 syslog
_elementtree        collections         nntplib             tabnanny
_functools          colorsys            ntpath              tarfile
_hashlib            compileall          nturl2path          telnetlib
_heapq              concurrent          numbers             tempfile
_imp                configparser        olefile             termios
_io                 contextlib          opcode              test
_json               copy                operator            textwrap
_locale             copyreg             optparse            this
_lsprof             crypt               os                  threading
_lzma               csv                 parser              time
_markupbase         ctypes              pathlib             timeit
_md5                curses              pdb                 tkinter
_multibytecodec     cython              pickle              token
_multiprocessing    datetime            pickletools         tokenize
_opcode             dbm                 pip                 trace
_operator           decimal             pipes               traceback
_osx_support        difflib             pkg_resources       tracemalloc
_pickle             dis                 pkgutil             tty
_posixsubprocess    distutils           platform            turtle
_pydecimal          doctest             plistlib            turtledemo
_pyio               dummy_threading     poplib              types
_random             easy_install        posix               typing
_scproxy            email               posixpath           unicodedata
_sha1               encodings           pprint              unittest
_sha256             ensurepip           profile             urllib
_sha3               enum                pstats              uu
_sha512             errno               pty                 uuid
_signal             faulthandler        pwd                 venv
_sitebuiltins       fcntl               py_compile          wand
_socket             filecmp             pyclbr              warnings
_sqlite3            fileinput           pydoc               wave
_sre                fnmatch             pydoc_data          weakref
_ssl                formatter           pyexpat             webbrowser
_stat               fractions           pyocr               wsgiref
_string             ftplib              pytesseract         xdrlib
_strptime           functools           pyximport           xml
_struct             gc                  queue               xmlrpc
_symtable           genericpath         quopri              xxlimited
_sysconfigdata_m_darwin_darwin getopt              random              xxsubtype
_testbuffer         getpass             re                  zipapp
_testcapi           gettext             readline            zipfile
_testimportmultiple glob                reprlib             zipimport
_testmultiphase     grp                 resource            zlib
_thread             gzip                rlcompleter         
_threading_local    hashlib             runpy
```

Comment: looks to me like the path is not set "tried paths: []" the list of paths it looked in is empty. also there is this post you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003117/python-doesnt-find-magickwand-libraries-despite-correct-location

Comment: That's a lot of information that is irrelevant. Try to cut it down to what we need to know in order to help you. For instance, you can cut out most of the output from both of those commands, just leave the parts in that show us what we need.

Comment: Set `MAGICK_HOME` environment variable to the location of ImageMagick's homebrew install.