# convert pdf to image(jpg) in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.6, imagemagick-convert, wand

I use python 3.6 , i want to convert the pdf document (contains 3 pages) to jpg images (3 jpg) . i tried to use wand and it is not successful and it is asking to check imagemagick as well in python library.
Can anyone please help me in this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Wand calls Imagemagick to do its work. So you must install Imagemagick so that Wand can find it. But you must install either Imagemagick 6 or Imagemagick 7 whichever is compatible with Wand. Most likely that is Imagemagick 6.  Sorry, I know little more about Wand.

Comment: I have used pdf2image for converting pdf to image. you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184239/python-extract-a-page-from-a-pdf-as-a-jpeg)