# converting pdf to image but after zooming in

Tags: image, pdf, ocr, python-tesseract, poppler

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184239/python-extract-a-page-from-a-pdf-as-a-jpeg) shows how `pdf`s could be converted to images. Is there a way to zoom my `pdf`s before converting to images? In my project, i am converting `pdf`s to `png`s and then using `Python-tesseract` library to extract text. I noticed that if I zoom `pdf`s and then save parts as `png`s then OCR provides much better results. So is there a way to zoom pdfs before converting to pngs?

Comment: You can also create a High resolution image from PDF and crop the image section which you need to OCR.

Comment: could you show how to do that? I need to do OCR on the whole page

Comment: could you provide some pdf examples?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that raising the quality (resolution) of your image is a better solution than zooming into the pdf.

using `pdf2image` you can accomplish this quite easily:

install pdf2image: `pip install pdf2image`

then, in python, convert your pdf into a high quality image:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pages = convert_from_path('sample.pdf', 400) #400 is the Image quality in DPI (default 200)

pages[0].save("sample.png")
```

by playing around with the quality parameter you should get the result you desider

Comment: any idea how high we could go on DPI? please provide a documentation link. I tried python help but it was that useful

Comment: @user2543622 it depends on the pdf you are working on and your computer memory, here is the wikipedia link for dpi:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch