# Extract image data based on coordinates or tessaract and writing the content in docs/docx word file

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, image-processing

I have image.want to extract image data with same layout  into docx file and in readable form using python.i have tried 
Applied tessaract on image and converting to pdf using pyteesaract
Then converting pdf to word file
But i am not able to maintain the layout and format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us the code you have tried so far and the problems you are having? Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered before [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305385/converting-pdf-to-image-but-after-zooming-in). You can use the pdf2image library for this issue:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pages = convert_from_path('sample.pdf', 400) //400 is the Image quality in DPI (default 200)

pages[0].save("sample.png")
```

Comment: I want to extract the data from image to docs/docx file with layout structure .

Comment: There are plenty libraries for python that do this, have you tried any of them? For example this one: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/