# convert pdf with filled form fields to image

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, aws-lambda

After much searching and experimenting, I cannot find a way to programmatically generate an image from a PDF file which contains filled form fields.  More specifically, it's not that the libraries I've tried don't generate an image (they do!), but the filled form fields end up blank.

Can anyone point me to a library/solution that works?  Ideally in python or javascript, but I'd take just about anything at this point.  Ultimately, it needs to end up as an AWS Lambda function.

I'm going to keep trying, but so far PyMuPDF and ImageMagick (ghostscript) don't seem to work, unless there's some options to enable it that I'm missing.

Comment: Of course, right after I post the question, I discovered that pdftoppm works in bash. So I'm proceeding to test python solutions based on it, like pdf2image.

Answer (score 0):

pdf2image (pdftoppm) correctly handles filled form fields.  I tested it using this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48583124/2009581