# How to convert pdf to jpg using shell command in python?

Tags: python, shell, pdf, imagemagick

This is the code I have tried:

```
import os

path = r'/Users/J2015/Desktop'

order = 'convert -density 100 -colorspace rgb {} {}'.format(os.path.join(path, r'testfile.pdf') , os.path.join(path, r'testimage.jpg'))
os.system(order)
```

However I recieve the following error:

> sh: convert: command not found

I wish to use ImageMagic for this conversion. Could you please tell me what's wrong?
Do I need read or write to have the final .jpg file? And is it possible to extend it to a couple of .pdf converting?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PDFTOJPGPATH = r"path of your converter pdftojpg.exe"
PDFFILE = "your pdf file.pdf"

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('"%s" -jpg "%s" out' % (PDFTJPGPATH, PDFFILE))
```

Comment: Could you tell me from where you found pdftojpg, I just checked poppler directory but couldn't find any pdftojpg.exe

Answer (score 0):

The command you are executing is missing `magick` in the beginning.
According to the [docs](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php), the command is
`magick convert ...`
Hence your code should be like this,

```py
import os

path = r'/Users/J2015/Desktop' # this should be the absolute path to you pdf and image file, here I have simply kept it as the author of the question for easy understanding of the changes I mentioned.

order = 'magick convert -density 100 -colorspace rgb {} {}'.format(os.path.join(path, r'testfile.pdf') , os.path.join(path, r'testimage.jpg'))
os.system(order)
```

Comment: The error is actually the shell telling you ```command convert is unknown```, i.e convert is not a recognised command or executable file, which is true, as ```magick convert``` is the command.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed Imagemagic properly? Are you able to do it outside python? I.e directly from the shell?

Comment: `os.system` is deprecated, you need `shell=True`, see [replacing-os-system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system)

Comment: @ManuSPillai convert: no images defined `/Users/J2015/Desktop/testimage.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.

Comment: @stovfl Good to know, Thanks!

Comment: Provide the full correct path to the pdf and image, i.e ```C://..```

Comment: I am using MacOS and the files are located in the desktop!

Comment: @J2015 are you able to do it through the shell directly?

Comment: Also, if you want to use Imagemagic just to convert your pdf to image. Doing it using a python package is a better approach I suggest, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184239/extract-a-page-from-a-pdf-as-a-jpeg#) can help you with that.

Comment: @ManuSPillai Now i'm using subprocess.call(command, shell=True) to run the command, it works perfectly when command is 'date' , however, I think problem is all in the command line and maybe output file as image output.