# who I can use python3 and wnad to convert pdf to png

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, png, wand

good night,

I read that I can convert every page of a pdf document in a different image and for that I could use wand do U have any ideia how I can do that I alredy tried to see in the documentation but I didn't understood anything :(

I appreciate your help :)

P.S: I use windows 10 / I saw diferent option for each os.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question seems to contain very less to no information to find the issue / problem that you are facing. Please be more elaborative.

Comment: I found an answer to my quest this is the link
[solution for the problem with pdf2image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184239/extract-a-page-from-a-pdf-as-a-jpeg)