# Detect and analyze text using Amazon Textract from a multi page document PDF synchronously

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ocr, amazon-textract

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62174368/8117673

Further question is - will it affect the **accuracy of text detection** by Amazon Textract?

Do I need to pre-process the image to get better result from Amazon Textract?

Answer (score 0):

I converted PDF to PNG using command [pdftoppm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftoppm#:%7E:text=Pdftoppm%20converts%20Portable%20Document%20Format,%2C%20PPM%2Droot%2Dnnnnnn.). In Python -> `subprocess.Popen(['pdftoppm -png Sample.pdf Sample'])`

The accuracy of Amazon Textract on PDF file was more than the PNG format. Because PDF is the original document.

Comment: What sort of inaccuracies did you see with PNG? Are more blocks detected in PDF? Did you see more inaccuracies in text with PNG files vs PDF?

Comment: @Zakir the inaccuracy was with text in PNG.