# Trying to loop through multiple PDF files and save the individual pages of those PDF as images

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf2image

I am working on a python project which requires me to loop through the multiple pdfs one by one stored in a folder called sample/ of my current directory and save the individual pages of those pdfs as images in another directory called converted_images/. Can someone help me? all the pdfs are named randomly but have a ".pdf" extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract a page from a pdf as a jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184239/extract-a-page-from-a-pdf-as-a-jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `pdf2image`

```
pip install pdf2image
```

```
    from pdf2image import convert_from_path
    pages = convert_from_path('pdf_file', 500)
    for page in pages:
        page.save('out.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

or:

```
import pypdfium2 as pdfium

pdffile = 'path/to/your_doc.pdf'

# render multiple pages concurrently (in this case: all)
for image, suffix in pdfium.render_pdf(pdffile):
    image.save(f'output_{suffix}.jpg')

# render a single page (in this case: the first one)
with pdfium.PdfContext(pdffile) as pdf:
    image = pdfium.render_page(pdf, 0)
    image.save('output.jpg')
```