# How can I make pdf2image work with PDFs that have paths containing Chinese characters?

Tags: python, image, pdf

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184239/extract-a-page-from-a-pdf-as-a-jpeg), I tried to run the following code to convert PDF with a path that contains Chinese characters to images:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
images = convert_from_path('path with Chinese character in it/some Chinese character.pdf', 500)
# save images
```

I got this error message:

```
PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'path with Chinese character in it/??????.pdf': No such file or directory.
```

in which all Chinese characters are replaced with "?".

The issue is caused solely by the Chinese characters in the directory since the program worked as intended after I ensured that the path contains no Chinese characters.

In `pdf2image.py`, I tried to alter the function `pdfinfo_from_path`, that `out.decode("utf8", "ignore")` is changed to e.g. `out.decode("utf32", "ignore")`, which also does not work.

Not sure whether it is relevant: according to the aforementioned answer, I also need to install poppler. But my code also worked when the directory does not contain any Chinese characters. In addition, running this code `conda install -c conda-forge poppler` (from the answer above) never ends after several hours of waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `convert_from_bytes` to avoid the issue:

```py
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes

with open('chinese_filename.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    images = convert_from_bytes(f.read(), 500)
```

Comment: wow, that was fast :o

Comment: @kosciej16 Gotta help people get things done :)