# Error: MagickWand shared library not found. You probably had not installed ImageMagick library. (even though I have)

Tags: python, django, imagemagick

I've installed [Imagemagick](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-mac) and [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/) however I get this error message when trying to start my django server:

```
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  brew install freetype imagemagick
```

so I perform `brew install freetype imagemagick` and then it responds with:

```
Warning: freetype 2.9.1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.9.1, run `brew reinstall freetype`
Warning: imagemagick 7.0.8-2 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 7.0.8-2, run `brew reinstall imagemagick`
```

so I perform `brew reinstall imagemagick` and then it returns the original error:

```
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  brew install freetype imagemagick
```

and this cycle continues. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Perhaps there is a conflict. It looks like you have ImageMagick 7 installed, but perhaps Wand needs Imagemagick 6. Perhaps you have seen this, but if not review http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/#requirements for installation notes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found\[windows\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894919/importerror-magickwand-shared-library-not-foundwindows)

Answer (score 0):

This github issue helped me solve the problem https://github.com/HazyResearch/pdftotree/issues/50#issuecomment-493386622
I had installed the library but somehow it was not linking properly. So i tried the steps provided in above link and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

The same question you will find on StackOverflow where I have answered in detail please check the answer there: [ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found[windows]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894919/importerror-magickwand-shared-library-not-foundwindows)

You need to install imagemagick in Jupyter and then download and install .exe executable for ImageMagick on Windows.